# Selenium error with javascript file upload validation

Tags: jquery, file-upload, selenium, jquery-validate

I am trying to create functional tests using Selenium (on Django / Python), but my javascript file validation brings up an error. My site basically takes a csv file as input and then presents a bunch of graphics to visualize the csv data in different ways. I am using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to check that it is a csv file via 1) extension is .csv, and 2) the mime-type is text/*.

This validates fine manually when I upload a .csv file, but when I try to upload the same file in Selenium, I get a mime-type error. Is there a way to "set" the file input's mime-type, or should I even have to do that? Am I missing something about file uploading in Selenium? I know I'm not supposed to click the file button and am sending the full path using send_keys().

I haven't found any similar questions on SO or Google. Almost every Selenium mime-type question deals with downloading files during test, instead of uploading files.

Thanks for your help!

My Selenium test code:

```
file_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('grade_file')
file_input.send_keys('/<FULLPATH>/grades_deid.csv')

grade_form = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
grade_form.submit()
```

The error I get during my test:

[image]

My jQuery validation code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Validate the file input so only csv files allowed
    $('#grade_form').validate({
        rules: {
            grade_file: {
                required: true,
                extension: "csv",
                accept: "text/*"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATED:
So after playing around some, I think this is due to how Chromedriver (not real Chrome) handles file mimetypes...my csv file works fine with the Firefox Selenium webdriver. Do  Chromedriver and Chrome use different mimetype sources? Should they be the same?